# Equivalent of System.Character.TCharHelper.IsWhiteSpace / IsLetter / IsNumber for AnsiChar

Tags: delphi

What is the equivalent of `System.Character.TCharHelper.IsWhiteSpace` / `IsLetter` / `IsNumber` for `AnsiChar` (UTF8)?

Comment: What is `anyString` ? A self-made type definition? If so, what is it defined as?

Comment: And what should it do with a string of "8a " ? Is it white space? Is it number? Is it letter? Or is it all three?

Comment: @HeartWare : spelling mistake i mean ansistring of course

Comment: And what about the string "8a " - is it WhiteSpace, Number and/or Letter?

Comment: @HeartWare hmm i see what you mean, i was speaking on each character. somethink like C: ansichar; c.isWhiteSpace

Comment: So you don't mean `AnsiString` but `AnsiChar` ?

Comment: @HeartWare yes sorry i just updated the question ....

Comment: Question is meaningless. UTF-8 is a variable length encoding. What would you do with any byte > 127, part of a multi byte sequence?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: utf16 is also a variable length encoding ;)

Comment: @loki I know. You asked about UTF-8 though, so let's stay on topic.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : i stay on the topic, System.Character.TCharHelper.IsWhiteSpace exist and work with variable length encoding (UTF16), so this why i say that nothing forbid it for UTF8. their is no reason to separate the logic between utf16 and utf8, both work similary

Comment: `TCharHelper.IsWhiteSpace` needs a Unicode code point. The version that operates on a `WideChar` clearly can't handle variable length UTF-16 encodings. The version that accepts `UCS4Char` can, and likewise the version that accepts a string and an index, because it can read the trail char. I think it should be obvious that you cannot encode a multibyte UTF-8 sequence in an `AnsiChar`.

Answer (score 2):

In general, it does not make sense to ask whether a single UTF-8 element (single byte) represents a whitespace. That's because UTF-8 is a variable length encoding and a code point may require more than a single byte to define it.

So you cannot ask whether or not a single byte is a whitespace, unless it encodes an ASCII character, i.e. < 128.

What you would need to do is to take the sequence of bytes that encode the code point of interest, and convert them into a UTF-32 value in a `UCS4Char` variable. Then pass that to the `UCS4Char` overload of `TCharHelper.IsWhiteSpace`.

However, that approach is not well supported by the Delphi libraries. The simplest way to do what you wish in Delphi is:

1. Convert your UTF-8 string to be a native UTF-16 Delphi `string`.
2. Use `TCharHelper.IsWhiteSpace(str, index)` to query for the code point at position `index`.

Answer (score 1):

If your question goes as to how to check if a UTF8-string variable is all white spaces, you can use the following RECORD HELPER:

```
TYPE
  U8StringHelper  = RECORD HELPER FOR UTF8String
                      FUNCTION IsAllWhiteSpaces : BOOLEAN;
                    END;

FUNCTION U8StringHelper.IsAllWhiteSpaces : BOOLEAN;
  VAR
    C : CHAR;
    S : UnicodeString;

  BEGIN
    S:=Self;
    FOR C IN S DO IF NOT C.IsWhiteSpace THEN EXIT(FALSE);
    Result:=TRUE
  END;
```

Then you can use it as in:

```
VAR
  U8 : UTF8String;

BEGIN
  U8:='  '#13#10;
  IF U8.IsAllWhiteSpaces THEN WRITELN('Yes') ELSE WRITELN('No');
  U8:='  X'#13#10;
  IF U8.IsAllWhiteSpaces THEN WRITELN('Yes') ELSE WRITELN('No');
END.
```

This will write out "Yes" followed by "No".

But please beware, that by defining your own helper for the UTF8String type, you are eliminating the access to any that may have been defined by the system. If that is a problem, you'll have to make a standard function instead:

```
FUNCTION IsAllWhiteSpaces(CONST U8 : UTF8String) : BOOLEAN;
  VAR
    C : CHAR;
    S : UnicodeString;

  BEGIN
    S:=U8;
    FOR C IN S DO IF NOT C.IsWhiteSpace THEN EXIT(FALSE);
    Result:=TRUE
  END;
```

and use it as follows:

```
VAR
  U8 : UTF8String;

BEGIN
  U8:='  '#13#10;
  IF IsAllWhiteSpaces(U8) THEN WRITELN('Yes') ELSE WRITELN('No');
  U8:='  X'#13#10;
  IF IsAllWhiteSpaces(U8) THEN WRITELN('Yes') ELSE WRITELN('No');
END.
```

I'll leave the making of the other IsXXX functions up to the reader...

Comment: The question is not "how to check if a UTF8-string variable is all white spaces"

Answer (score 0):

Okay - after we have finally determined the proper question, the easiest way for you is to simply cast-up the AnsiChar variable to a proper UNICODE char and then do your thing.

```
VAR
  A : AnsiChar;

BEGIN
  IF CHAR(A).IsLetter THEN ...
END.
```

**HOWEVER**: working with individual characters from a UTF-8 string is not advisable, as many characters (by the very nature of UTF-8) consists of **TWO** characters. You are therefore not able to decide if a single AnsiChar from UTF-8 string is anything, as it can merely be a "prefix"/"escape" character, and the actual character is the following character from the string.

So the best way would be to have your UTF8-String and assign it to a UNICODE string variable, and then use the proper CHAR type to iterate over it.

If your question is how to "convert" an AnsiString encoded in UTF-8 into a UNICODE string, you can use the following routine:

```
FUNCTION AnsiUTF8toUNICODE(CONST S : AnsiString) : STRING;
  BEGIN
    Result:=UTF8ToUnicodeString(RawString(S))
  END;
```

Comment: Casting an `AnsiChar` to `WideChar` is not correct, unless the `AnsiChar` happens to be an ASCII character.